# Two consecutive parentheses after name in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, porting

Please excuse me for this amateurish question,

I'm trying to convert some Matlab code to Python, I don't have any experience with Matlab but so far I have been able to deduce what the Matlab code does and the conversion so far has been successful.

But now I am stuck at these lines of code;

```
        SERAstart = []
        for n=1:length(bet)
            alf = -bet(n) * 1e-2;
            SERAstart = [SERAstart(alf - i * bet(n))(alf + i * bet(n))];
        end
```

What I don't understand is this line;

```
SERAstart(alf - i * bet(n))(alf + i * bet(n))
```

Two consecutive parentheses after "SERAstart", are they nested array indexing? are they indexing and then function call to return of indexing? are they function call and then function call again to return value of first call?

Please help me understand what is going on here so that I can convert it to Python.

I realize that it might not be possible just from the piece of code I have posted to say definitively what it does, but otherwise if you can help guide me to how to figure it out (without the use of Matlab) then I would also be very grateful.

Thanks a lot for any help!.

**EDIT:**

This is my own attempt at a conversion, but I don't know if this makes sense;

```
        # SERAstart = [];
        SERAstart = [[]]
        # for n=1:length(bet)
        for n in range(len(bet)):
            # alf = -bet(n) * 1e-2;
            alf = -bet[n] * 1e-2
            # SERAstart = [SERAstart(alf - i * bet(n))(alf + i * bet(n))];
            SERAstart = [SERAstart[alf - 1j * bet[n]][alf + 1j * bet[n]]]
        # end
```

**EDIT2:**

I just noticed this line in the documentation relating to SERAstart:

```
        % SERAstart(N,1) : vector of starting poles [rad/sec]
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure there is no typo and this code runs ? As it is, It fails on my MATLAB R2016a, giving the error I would have expected: `Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.`

Comment: @Hoki No I am not 100% sure, but 99.9% though. The code I am converting is this; https://www.sintef.no/globalassets/project/vectfit/matrix_fitting_toolbox_1.zip ..I just received access to Matlab so I will try now to run the original code in Matlab just to make sure it actually works in full in matlab, but it definitely should/I expect it to...

Comment: multiple consecutive index are allowed with Octave, so it could be an Octave synthax. But there is no such things as complex number index.

Comment: @obchardon "But there is no such things as complex number index" No that also puzzles me, I also concluded that the value resulting inside the parenthesis is complex... But then what could it be? Since you can't use complex index it must be something other than indexing going on right? or...

Comment: @obchardon I just realized that the index is not complex, the array "bet" is defined as ```        bet = linspace(s(1) / i, s(Ns) / i, N / 2);``` so the resulting value is real (after multiplying bet[index] by j)